# extract block from XML with different ending tags (<tag>...</tag> vs <tag ... />)

Tags: xml

Given an XML with some blocks ending within the same tag and others with a separate tag:

```
<parent name="parent_1" team="team_a">
  <child name="child_1" team="team_b"/>
</parent>
<parent name="parent_2" team="team_c"/>
<parent name="parent_3" team="team_b"/>
```

How can extract the block for a given name?

I have:

```
awk "/<parent name=\"$name\"/,/<\/parent>/" $file
```

which would work for $name=parent_1, and:

```
awk "/<parent name=\"$name\"/,/\/>/" $file
```

which would work for parent_2 or parent_3 but not sure how to do both.

I tried:

```
awk "/<parent name=\"$name\"/,/[\/>|<\/parent>]/" $file
```

as an OR condition but for parent_1 it still gives me:

```
    <parent name="parent_1" team="team_a">
```

Can that be done?

Comment: awk is not a XML parser, use xmllint, xmlstarlet or xidel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a proper `xml` parser: `xmllint`:

file:

```
<root>
<parent name="parent_1" team="team_a">
  <child name="child_1" team="team_b"/>
</parent>
<parent name="parent_2" team="team_c"/>
<parent name="parent_3" team="team_b"/>
</root>
```

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//parent[@name="parent_1"]' file
<parent name="parent_1" team="team_a">
  <child name="child_1" team="team_b"/>
</parent>
```

Comment: Ha - thanks Gilles. This seems way more appropriate indeed